# Android: AlertDialog цвет заднего фона заголовка

Tags: android, android-dialog

Есть очередной `AlertDialog`:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(Main.this)
        .setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
        .setSingleChoiceItems(new String[]{...}, 0, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface i2, int i3) {
                ...
            }

        })
        .setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(R.string.ok), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface i2, int i3) {
                ...
            }

        })
        .setNegativeButton(getResources().getString(R.string.cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface i1, int i2) {
                ...
            }

        })
        .create()
        .show();
```

Как изменить задний фон его заголовка? К примеру, нужен красный. Вот пример что именно нужно:

[image: AlertDialog]

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте создать собственный элемент заголовка. Например,
res/layout/title_view.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/BACKGROUND_COLOR" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLargePopupMenu"
        android:paddingLeft="?attr/dialogPreferredPadding"
        android:paddingRight="?attr/dialogPreferredPadding"
        android:paddingTop="9dp"
        android:paddingBottom="9dp"
        android:textColor="@color/TEXT_COLOR" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

И после этого его можно будет использовать так:

```
View titleView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.title_view, null);
TextView title = (TextView) titleView.findViewById(R.id.title);
title.setText("About Android Dialog Box");

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setItems(items, clickListener);
builder.setCustomTitle(customTitleView);

AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```

Comment: получается, но не всё. Цвет фона то зелёный, но вот текст из TextView не отображается. то есть просто сплошной зелёный заголовок. я на 100% удостоверился, что ресурс текста указан корректно, и его цвет не зелёный, а белый. что может быть не так?